# Multiple values selection in <g:select> error

Tags: grails

I'm trying to use multiple values for a select using `<g:select multiple='true'>`, but when i try to save the form to the DB, i got this error

```
Property [Languages] of class [class com.Myapp.hr.EmploymentSeeker] with value [french,english] is not contained within the list [[french, english, russian, chinese]]
```

here is my Domain:

```
class EmploymentSeeker {
 Set<String> languages = [] as Set
 static hasMany = [ languages: String ]
 static constraints = {
languages(nullable:true,inList:Holders.config.languages)
 }

}
```

Config file :

```
languages=[
'french',
'english',
'russian',
'chinese'
]
```

GSP:

```
<g:select  multiple="true" name="languages" from="${employmentSeekerInstance.constraints.languages.inList}" value="${employmentSeekerInstance?.languages}" valueMessagePrefix="empSeeker.languages" noSelection="['': '']"/>
```

what may cause this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Grails doc:

> **inList**: Constrains a value so that it must be contained within the given list.

The problem is that your *inList* constrant it's a list of Strings, but `languages` from `EmploymentSeeker` isn't a **String**, it's a **Set**.

If it was a **String**, it would work, for example:
`'french'` is contained in `['french','english','russian','chinese']`
But you have a **Set**, so
`['french']` isn't contained in `['french','english','russian','chinese']`

To make it work with *inList* you have to set in the constraint list all the combinations that user could choose, like:
`[['french'], ['french', 'english'], ['english', 'french'] ...]` and so on.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22045909/4769188) answer describes how to archive those combinations, but actually it's not a good solution, because `subsequences()` doesn't care about permutations. However, adding permutations will increase your constraint list exponentially after growing of languages list.

As you can see, using **inList** is not a good solution in your case.

I would recomment to implement your custom simple constraint, like this:

```
languages(nullable:true,validator: {value, object ->
                Holders.config.languages.containsAll(value)​​​)​
        })
```

You can read about custom constraints [here](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/12/grails-custom-validation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038905/how-do-i-create-a-custom-validator-with-a-custom-error-message-in-grails)

Comment: what about the `from` in `<g:select  multiple="true" name="languages" from="${employmentSeekerInstance.constraints.languages.inList}" value="${employmentSeekerInstance?.languages}" valueMessagePrefix="empSeeker.languages" noSelection="['': '']"/>`

Comment: @Sherif, you can use your original languages list:
`from="${Holders.config.languages}"`

Comment: thanks , regarding the domain design of multiple select values , is what i'm doing right or there is a another handy way ?